# how to use huggingface models without downloading model into local machine

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

I was using Huggingface models in my python code. When I run the code its downloads everything in my local machine and it takes almost a long time to respond back. Since the model files are in my system, it occupied all my drive space. What is the other alter method I can use rather than downloading. Please help me.

how to use huggingface models without downloading model into local machine by using APIs.

Comment: In this case, you may use their Inference API. Check here: https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/index

Comment: I believe they charges for inference API. Here im planning for a complete opensource application. So do you have any other idea? The model I'm gonna use is "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b"

Answer (score 0):

You can use together ai to use the model but you will have topay for it. They will provide you $25 free credit at sign up. Hope this helps.